# Analytical solution for length of star trails?

Tags: calculus, integration, angle, spheres

Assuming there is an (infinitely) large sphere (the sky) that rotates counterclockwise as seen from above around its axis of rotation (which goes through its center point) at a fixed rate ω_sky, with a point (star) on its inner surface at 0° ≤ φ_star < 360°, -90° ≤ θ_star ≤ 90°.

In the center, a vector (a startracker) is aligned with the axis of rotation toward the north pole, but misaligned by a degree (say, θ_tracker = 90°- , =1°, φ_tracker=0°) and rotates at the same rate and in the same direction as the sky.

Finally, a vector (camera) is fixed to the rotation of that vector, but is initally pointed to the star.

[image]

Over a duration (full rotation of both sky + (tracker+camera)), from the perspective of the camera, the point/star describes a closed path.

Viewed from the outside of the sphere, fixed on the changing point on the sphere the camera points to (red dot):

[image: from the outside]

From the inside, showing how the star/fixed point on the sphere changes position from the perspective of the camera:

[image: from the inside]

Which when stacked in a long exposure can look like this:

[image]

Typical exposures are much shorter, so their resulting trail is just a very short segment of this closed path.

Is it possible to calculate the length of this path (star trail) in degrees over a certain range of (exposure) time analytically, for a given star position and misalignment ?

Comment: I'm confused- why does the star move in the camera's field of view? The way you've defined things, isn't the whole system (including camera and star) rotating as one rigid object?

Comment: Maybe your camera is actually on a motor that rotates around the misaligned tracker axis (the red vector) in attempt to follow the star?

Comment: What kind of units do you need for the answer? Degrees, inches, pixels?

Comment: @JairTaylor Degrees, added to the question. The example picture is over one full rotation of the sky, usually exposures are much shorter, so the trail is just a short segment of the closed path

Comment: @Karl The sky and the (startracker+camera) rotate independently. The startracker rotation tries to compensate for the skies (apparent) rotation by rotating at the same speed

Comment: I see, you're thinking of the red arrow as an object that "spins" in addition to changing directions. It's a little confusing to call it a vector, since a vector doesn't carry any orientation information except its direction.

Comment: Yes, very true, not sure what else to call it

Comment: For me, it helps to think about the Earth rotating instead of the sky. The tracker rotates *relative to the Earth* around an axis that's meant to be parallel to the Earth's rotation axis so that the net motion relative to the sky is zero, but the tracker's misaligned axis actually rotates around the Earth's axis, resulting in a net motion that's some kind of wobble.

Comment: Does [this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ6Yd.gif) look consistent with the model? If so, the answer depends on precisely how the camera is (mis-)aligned with the star. (The black dot models the star, the blue dot models my understanding of a "typical" camera view, and the light blue dots represent the camera views if the camera is mis-aligned to point at the star exactly once per day.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think so

Comment: The star traces an ellipse, so the arc length can only be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. The shape of the ellipse depends on the camera's spatial orientation, not just the direction the camera is pointed. I don't have formulas, only a description as a product of rotation matrices that seems unlikely to be helpful to a non-mathematician. If a ballpark estimate is all that's needed, however, an analytic solution looks ... inefficient.